# How to header nav bar align using bootstrap css

Tags: css, angular8

I am trying to show below look but not working.I have added all css and js but not working.
How to align properly nav bar and logo for mobile view and desktop and tap.

Demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-bootstrap-navbar-ujihha?file=src/styles.css

[image]

header.component.html:

```
  <div id="page"> 
    <header class="header-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top-row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <div id="logo">
                            <!--<a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>-->
                            <a href="index.html"><span>Resort</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 visible-sm">
                        <div class="text-right"><button type="button" class="book-now-btn">Book Now</button></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove-padd">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                                <button data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>

                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navigation navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse remove-space">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled nav1 cl-effect-10">
                                    <li><a data-hover="Home" class="active"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a data-hover="About" href="about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a data-hover="Rooms" href="rooms.html"><span>Rooms</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a data-hover="Gallery" href="gallery.html"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a data-hover="Contact Us" href="contact.html"><span>contact Us</span></a></li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2  col-sm-4 col-xs-12 hidden-sm">
                        <div class="text-right"><button type="button" class="book-now-btn">Book Now</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--back to top--->
    <a style="display: none;" href="javascript:void(0);" class="scrollTop back-to-top" id="back-to-top">
        <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-angle-up fa-lg"></i></span>
        <span>Top</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: i think you are mixing different bootstrap versions syntax. You have pulled in bootstrap 4, but trying to use older version classes for hiding and visibility. For the `Book now` div next to the logo if you try using `col-sm-6 d-sm-block d-md-none` instead of `col-sm-6 visible-sm`. It will be visible only on small devices and the look will be good in desktop view. Read more on the classes here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: @Panther: But not working for mobile and tab view:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-bootstrap-navbar-mh2ruz?file=src/app/header/header.component.html

Comment: Yes. This looks like some custom made header. So you'll have to build it responsively. If you see in most bootstrap headers, everything will be inside `nav`. Also the logo is in `div` which takes up a whole row in mobile/tab. In general bootstrap templates, it would be in `a` tab. It would be good if you follow some existing template headers so as to not re-invent the wheel. Else you'll have to handle the responsiveness yourself.

Comment: @Panther: Can you send me best example or demo link for latest bootsrtap nav bar for logo also?